# how to write Dynamic SOQL query using Not equal operator

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

> MALFORMED_QUERY: 
>   Opportunity__r.LeadSource != 'Website');
>   ^
>   ERROR at Row:3:Column:89
>   unexpected token: ;

```
SELECT Id, OwnerId, WhatId,Reminder_Date_Time__c, WhoId,Record_Type_Name__c, Task_Type__c,
       Assigned_Date__c, Task_Status__c, ActivityDate, Subject, Attended_By__c,Is_Assigned__c 
FROM Task 
WHERE (Task_Status__c != 'Closed') AND ( Opportunity__r.LeadSource != 'Website')
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Your title mentions NOT LIKE but you do not have NOT LIKE in your query.

Answer (score 2):

SOQL queries do not end with a semi-colon. Please remove the semi-colon from the end of your query. The parentheses are also optional.

```
SELECT Id, OwnerId, WhatId,Reminder_Date_Time__c, WhoId,Record_Type_Name__c, Task_Type__c,
       Assigned_Date__c, Task_Status__c, ActivityDate, Subject, Attended_By__c,
       Is_Assigned__c 
FROM Task 
WHERE Task_Status__c != 'Closed' AND Opportunity__r.LeadSource != 'Website'
```

Comment: r8 @sfdcfox but it's give me wrong results

Comment: @user61059 how so? That wasn't in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this dynamic soql.

```
String query = 'SELECT Id, OwnerId, WhatId, Reminder_Date_Time__c, WhoId, Record_Type_Name__c, Task_Type__c, Assigned_Date__c, Task_Status__c, ActivityDate, Subject, Attended_By__c,Is_Assigned__c '+
               +'FROM Task '+
               +'WHERE Task_Status__c != \'Closed\' AND (NOT Opportunity__r.LeadSource LIKE \'%Website%\')';
System.debug(query);
```

Refer this link for more details http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/soql-sosl-using-not-like.html

For more on [Quoted String Escape Sequences](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_quotedstringescapes.htm)

Comment: it shows unexpected token NOT

Comment: SELECT Id, OwnerId, WhatId,Reminder_Date_Time__c, WhoId, Record_Type_Name__c, Task_Type__c,Assigned_Date__c, Task_Status__c, ActivityDate, Subject, Attended_By__c,Is_Assigned__c FROM Task WHERE ( Task_Status__c LIKE 'Open') AND( NOT Opportunity__r.LeadSource LIKE 'Website')                                            ***************************************************************************************************** i tried this one but it's not working  with my DB records

Comment: @user61059 Try the updated query

Comment: with one like and not equal operator it's works by removing parentheses in LIKE condition

Comment: But if i write `SELECT Id, OwnerId, WhatId,Reminder_Date_Time__c, WhoId, Record_Type_Name__c, Task_Type__c,Assigned_Date__c, Task_Status__c, ActivityDate, Subject, Attended_By__c,Is_Assigned__c                                   FROM Task WHERE (NOT Task_Status__c LIKE 'Closed') AND( Opportunity__r.LeadSource != 'Website')`                                         
                                                                                                                           ..  Still i m getting wrong results

Comment: **i store value inside value variable**                                                                      searchQuery = searchQuery +''+'NOT';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
searchQuery = searchQuery + ' ' + searchWrapper.fieldName + ' LIKE \'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(value.trim()) + '%\'';

Comment: SELECT Id, OwnerId, WhatId,Reminder_Date_Time__c, WhoId,Record_Type_Name__c, Task_Type__c,
           Assigned_Date__c, Task_Status__c, ActivityDate, Subject, Attended_By__c,
           Is_Assigned__c 
    FROM Task 
    WHERE (NOT Task_Status__c LIKE 'Closed') AND( Opportunity__r.LeadSource != 'Website')